# In-place Perl upgrade from source

Tags: perl

Is there a standard way to upgrade to a new, minor version (and binary compatible) of Perl without a full recompile from source?

For example, if I have Perl v5.24.0 installed with a bunch of CPAN modules, can I upgrade this installation to v5.24.1 without recompiling a whole new build and doing the same for all of the CPAN modules installed under v5.24.0? Or do I have to create a list of all installed CPAN modules, compile a new Perl, and reinstall those CPAN modules using the newly compiled version?

I'm not seeing an easy way to "patch" the current system, using the source code from the latest release. (Note: I'm wondering if there is a native way to do this (i.e., not using perlbrew)).

Comment: You shouldn't need to reinstall your modules.

Comment: Related: http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2009/05/perl-5-and-binary-compatibility.html

Comment: Don't care about the down-votes. This is StackOverflow, here are some users who thinks that the only right perl question is like _how to reverse a list in perl_ or such, of course with the provided code. They forget that here are also on-topic ([help/on-topic]) questions about: _software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development_ - your question is fully in-line with the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if I have Perl v5.24.0 installed with a bunch of CPAN modules, can I upgrade this installation to v5.24.1 without recompiling a whole new build

As far as I know, no. You have to configure/compile/install the new perl from scratch.

> and doing the same for all of the CPAN modules installed under v5.24.0?

Yes: `Configure` asks you about existing perl versions and whether it should include their directories in `@INC`. If you say yes (which I believe is the default), all already installed modules are available in your new perl.

---

That said:

> Or do I have to create a list of all installed CPAN modules

This is easy with `cpan -a`:

```
$ cpan -a
... lots of modules listed here ...

Wrote bundle file
    /home/user/.cpan/Bundle/Snapshot_2017_04_25_00.pm
```

> and reinstall those CPAN modules using the newly compiled version?

After installing the new Perl, run

```
$ cpan Bundle::Snapshot_2017_04_25_00
```

(or whatever name `cpan -a` gave the snapshot file in the previous step) and it should install everything you had before.

Comment: Thank you. This works as a solution. I am still surprised there's not a direct builtin that can upgrade to the latest minor release.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using perlbrew it has an 'upgrade-perl' command. The downside is that the initial configure parameters still aren't passed to the newly built version.
See also http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2013/03/upgrade-in-place-with-perlbrew.html